# In Java, how to create a simple program that prints the number of consonants and vowels in a phrase?

Tags: java

Here is what I have so far:

```
 System.out.println("CONSONANT AND VOWEL COUNTER: Please type a phrase: ");
    String lastPhrase = keyboard.nextLine();

    int countCon = 0;
    int countVow = 0;

    if (lastPhrase.contains("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")) {
        countVow++;
    }
    if (lastPhrase.contains("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLIMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")) {
        countCon++;
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + countVow + " vowels and " + countCon + " consonants.");
```

It comes up 0 for both values. What's the problem?

Comment: You are asking whether `lastPhrase` contains these long strings. Does it?

Comment: You will need `loops` and `charAt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Java documentation

String contains(CharSequence s)
Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

Simplest way to count number of vowels is to loop through and check each character of a String object.

```
String s = "Whatever you want it to be.".toLowercase();
int vowelCount = 0;
for (int i = 0, i < s.length(); ++i) {
    switch(s.charAt(i)) {
        case 'a':
            vowelCount++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            vowelCount++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            vowelCount++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            vowelCount++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            vowelCount++;
            break;
        default:
            // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be much better to use String.matches() and a regex for vowels and consonants. Not much more complicated either.

Comment: Agree. There are multiple ways to solve this problem. String.matches() is a more elegant way but Zander has to come out with the regex first.

Answer (score 4):

`contains` searches for the entire String, not the individual letters.

The simplest way to do this, from the top of my head assuming there's no magical String method I'm missing, would be to manually check each character.

You should convert the entire string to upper case using `toUpperCase` and then check if the character is a vowel AEIOU.

```
if(string.charAt(i) == 'A' || ... /* and so on */) {
    countVow++;
}
else {
    countCons++;
}
```

If it is, add 1 to vowels. Else, add 1 to consonants. It's either a vowel or a consonant, so if you just check those five characters, you know what it is.

Since this is probably a homework problem, I've provided you a step in the right direction. You should work towards the solution and come back if you need help.

Comment: What if the string has numbers or punctuation? Then it won't work.

Comment: @RenéG then you'd use `isLetter()` in the `else` as an `else if`.

Comment: I tried this but it says first type boolean second type char. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like that

```java
String vowels = "aeuyio";
String consonants = "bcdfgh..."

String phrase = "amsdasmdnsn";

int vowelsCount = 0, consonantsCount = 0;
for (char ch : phrase.toCharArray()) {
    if (vowels.contains(String.valueOf(ch))) {
        ++vowelsCount;
    }

    if (consonants.contains(String.valueOf(ch))) {
        ++consonantsCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
//convert string to lowercase
//for loop looping over the string    
if(string.charAt(i).matches([aeiou]) {
        countVow++;
}
else if(isLetter(string.charAt(I))){
        countCons++;  
} //end for loop
```

Look at [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) and [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

String.contains works only with strings and Regular Expressions. The fastest way to count all consonants i can think of is:

```
String onlyConsonants = lastPhrase.replaceAll("[\\saeiouAEIOU0-9]", "");
countCon = onlyConsonants.length();
String onlyVowels = lastPhrase.replaceAll("[^\\saeiouAEIOU0-9]", "");
countVow = onlyVowels.length();
```

I think this solves your problem.